# Validate chain from `valid-headers` to `valid-fork`

Tags: blockchain, json-rpc, blockchain-fork, validation

The `getchaintips` JSON-RPC returns multiple branches of the blockchain.
Chain tips can be in various statuses.
The *active* and *valid-fork* are already validated chains. There is a *valid-header*

> `valid-headers` for a chain with valid headers whose corresponding blocks are stored locally, but which haven’t been fully validated

which I would like to turn into *valid-fork*. According to above info I have the blocks locally so I just need to invoke validation process.
Is there any RPC to perform that task? or any other way?